# How to do first bitbucket commit?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

So I'm very new to bitBucket. And I'm hoping for a very step wise simple answer.

1. I have a folder with all my code/project files.
2. I have a repository set up.

Now, how do I connect the two ? I'm looking online but everyone is showing different steps. I haven't written any command lines. What are the command lines from the beginning to the end for the my first initial push ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the BitBucket docs or their [Git tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud)?

Comment: do you have a command line and can you check inside your folder `git status` command works.

Comment: when i entered the line git clone http://...

It says "you appear to have cloned an empty repository. And it never prompts for a username and paswword after that. And thats what the tutorial asks you to do next. So im stuck here.

Comment: when i do git status, it says "Your branch is up to date with origin/master"

Comment: also im trying to upload an existing project, not make one from scratch

Comment: ok , so you need to do then couple of steps., let me know which os you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

open GitBash
and set Project Location Path

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin ORIGIN_URL 
git push -u origin master
```

**URL link this**
       https://keshavgera@bitbucket.org/keshavgera/ProjectName.git

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please go through this

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-unversioned-code-to-a-repository-877177133.html

Here it is clearly described how to add your code/project from your local machine to git repo.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git add --all

E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git commit -m 'Realm_Demo'

E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git push
```

**Again after modified**

```
E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git add --all
E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   SqliteDemo/Database.js
        modified:   SqliteDemo/src/ProductAddScreen.js
        modified:   SqliteDemo/src/ProductScreen.js


E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git commit -m "Sqlite Demo updated"

E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git pull
Already up to date.

E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>git push
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.54 KiB | 1.54 MiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Checking connectivity: 7, done.
To https://bitbucket.org/develop-eeziklik/ez-react-pocs.git
   0cea991..ae349a3  master -> master

E:\ReactAll\RealmDemo\ez-react-pocs>
```

Note :- git commit krne ke pad push leena hai and after that Push Krna hai